# Best Way to Split Server Process

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, pipe, fork

I am working on a building a server in C which not only listens for incoming connections, but also provides me with an interactive shell. Basically, I have something like this for accepting clients...

```c
while (1) {
    accept_client(serverfd);
}
```

And something like this for creating the interactive shell

```c
while (1) {
    printf("shell> ");
    fgets(command, sizeof(command) - 1, stdin);
    server_do(command);
}
```

I would like to run both loops in parallel, with the interactive shell being to access variables from the server in real time. I tried using [fork](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), which worked well, but was overall was not successful, since fork only creates a copy of the child process, and none of the variables can be updated as new connections happen. I also tried using a [pipe](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) to transmit data - but that was sort of a disaster (although I may have been doing it wrong). Finally I attempted to use [pthread](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html), but didn't see any obvious ways to make both run in parallel without blocking.

What is the "correct" way to do this? I have done a decent amount of research and haven't stumbled across an obvious answer.

Comment: As with many things in computing there is no single "correct" way so your question is not very answerable. Using threading is certainly *one* way to do it. If you want help with a particular solution then please show that code as a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and explain what problems you have with it. Otherwise your question as currently stated is too broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also treat 'stdin' like a 'network connection', they are both 'fd's in low-level view.

So you need to implement a server which handles multiple connections paralleled,
there are many approaches to do this.

Here is a good reading ([http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-book/01_intro.html](http://www.wangafu.net/%7Enickm/libevent-book/01_intro.html)) for explaining and comparing those approaches.

I would like implement in asynchronous fashion in your case.
I wrote some wrapper and sample (https://github.com/grizzlybears/tevpp)to make libevent easier to use. The 'cat' sample demonstrates handling stdio like normal connections. You may have interest.:)